# Is there a cross-browser standard on-load event for HTML's "object" tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am aware that IE supports the `onreadystatechange` attribute on the `object` tag, but this doesn't seem to be a standard way thus all other browsers do not support it.

Update: To clarify, I am not looking for the DOM Load event, I am looking for the load event of the `object` tag itself(e.g. an `object` tag embedding a PDF file into a page).

In a way, I am looking for something similar to `img`'s `onload` event /`complete` attribute for the `object` tag.

Comment: You just made my answer irrelevant with that edit

Comment: Anyone? Or is this really just not possible as of the moment?

Comment: `complete` is an event?! Isn't it a flag telling you is the image loading completed or not?

Comment: sorry, I meant the onload event/complete attribute. Updated question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The `<object onload>` attribute works well in latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera (I've just tested it).

Also, the expression `'onload' in document.createElement('object')` evaluates to `true` in Chrome and Opera; naturally, Firefox is an exception because such event support check doesn't work there generally. kangax describes cross-browser event support detection at http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

Comment: it is not cross browser, my initial sniff testing did reveal that you are correct but I haven't really tested it. I fear that this may have the same results as RASG's answer.

Comment: As far as I test it, Chrome does not fires the onload event when object src change and load.

Comment: Just chiming in from the future in 2019: Chrome no longer fires the `onload` event when something is loaded in the `<object>` element.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to trigger an event after the [PDF] object is loaded?
If so, this might help you:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=160792

----- EDITED [19/10/2011] -----

If you load the PDF inside an iframe, it will work.

Check this: http://sykari.net/stuff/iframe

The script will alert only **after** the PDF is completely loaded.
(Tested with FF7 + Win7).

----- EDITED [20/10/2011] -----

Using JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/fcABz

To be sure it is working i have added a 36 pages PDF file to the iframe, so you can watch the progress bar (at least in FF7 there is one, not sure about Chrome) going up, and after it is fully loaded, you will see an alert.

Why? Because the *.load* method from JQuery will wait until all subelements inside the iframe are loaded.

> The **load** event is sent to an element when **it and all sub-elements** have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, **iframes**, and the window object.

If you want to try more then once, clear the cache.
Or change the PDF to a bigger one, like this http://pubs.usgs.gov/tei/532/report.pdf (90 pages).

Comment: I am aware of the onreadystatechange in IE. onload does not seem to work in the latest version of FF. Also when I try: var object = document.createElement('object');
console.log('onload' in object);
I get false.

Comment: Tested your sample on chrome with the fourth link(the pdf). Event happens on DOMLoad of the iframe as expected and not after the PDF load as you said.

Comment: @Hyangelo Another try. Now with JQuery. Please check it.

Comment: Didn't work with latest Chrome(14.0.835), Firefox(8.0), and IE9. Alert showed up BEFORE the pdf even started loading. Alert didn't show up at all at the other browsers.

Comment: sorry to hear it didnt work for you, but believe me, the example works just like expected. maybe someone else can test it.

Comment: What browser and which version did you test it against anyway?

Comment: Tested with Firefox 7 and Firefox 8.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: The iframe solutions link is broken now. That's why the answer should include the relevant code in its body.

Comment: @IvanRubinson two things to say here: 1- the link to my jsfiddle is working. click it. 2- you are complaining about a 7 years old answer. there are LOTS of better answers on google today. don't be lazy.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can do this just using object attributes.

Have a look at this :

- You can try something using [`onreadystatechange`](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)

  When data is well loaded, `readyState==4` and `xmlhttp.status==200`
- You can try to use [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

  Export your `<object/>` in a page called `object.html`.

  In your main page include :

  `<div id="theObject"></div>
  <script>
        $("#theObject").load("object.html", 
                  function(response, status, xhr) { alert('Loaded : '+status);});
      </script>`

  The message will be display when the request completes.

Comment: No, this doesn't solve anything. The Object loads a data(say a PDF or flash). What I need is the event when that data has been fully loaded.