# How can I detect in angular, when a pdf is loaded?

Tags: angular

I am using the  tag to dynamically load pdfs. In my real project, I have heavy pdfs and that is why I would like to know if there is any way to detect when the pdf finishes loading and is ready.

how can I do it?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrak1m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<object *ngIf="link" [data]="link | safepipe" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"> </object>
{{link}}

<button (click)="link1()">pdf1</button>
<button (click)="link2()">pdf2</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cross-browser standard on-load event for HTML's "object" tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756353/is-there-a-cross-browser-standard-on-load-event-for-htmls-object-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the load method on object

template:

```
<object *ngIf="link" [data]="link | safepipe" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" (load)="loaded($event)"> </object>
    {{link}}

<button (click)="link1()">pdf1</button>
<button (click)="link2()">pdf2</button>
```

and define the method in ts

class:

```
loaded(e){
  console.log(e);
  // Do your thing here.
}
```

Comment: as in the the loaded method is not invoked??

Comment: the function never is triggered