# How to wait until an <object> loads in jquery 2?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm forced to use the Jquery version 2.2.4

This works perfect: waits 5 seconds to show a PDF and then show a message:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check pdf</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#pdf-holder").load(function () {
                    alert("Finish loading");
                });
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $("#pdf-holder").attr('src', 'file.pdf')
                }, 5000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe id="pdf-holder" width="60%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" >
             Your browser cannot display PDF files
        </iframe>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

But if change the iframe by an `object`, the PDF is loaded, but the message is not displayed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check pdf</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#pdf-holder").load(function () {
                    alert("Finish loading");
                });
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $("#pdf-holder").attr('data', 'file.pdf')
                }, 5000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <object id="pdf-holder" width="60%" height="500px" type="application/pdf" >
             Your browser cannot display PDF files
        </object>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

The problem is that  doesn't rise the onload (as pointed in the comments), but how can I know that a PDF has been fully loaded in 2022?

Comment: Most likely because an `<object>` doesn't raise a `load` event?  https://api.jquery.com/load-event (guessing)

Comment: **Danger**: That version of jQuery has known security vulnerabilities: https://security.snyk.io/package/npm/jquery/2.2.4

Comment: See this related (dup?) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756353/is-there-a-cross-browser-standard-on-load-event-for-htmls-object-tag

Comment: @Quentin Is not my code, I cannot change, just suggest to change ASAP

Comment: @freedomn-m In a comment in the question you posted say: "Just chiming in from the future in 2019: Chrome no longer fires the onload event when something is loaded in the <object> element", so you were right, <object> doesn't launches onload, I'll change the question: how to solve this problem?